# react native - render big FlatList with numColumns

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

FlatList is having issues, when I render many cells on the screen.

Please take a look at the below image first.

[image]

Let's say we have:

- A map with row x column = 80 x 80 = 6400 cells
- A button to enable and disable scroll feature

The issues:

1. The map render super slow, initial view, app has to call renderItem around 2000 times before it allows users to continue their actions
2. I am trying to change the `windowSize` and `initialNumToRender` but it doesn't help
3. When users press on `Enable/Disable Scroll`, the app has to call renderItem around 2000 times again even I set the `extraData` to only `cellList`

Question is:

- If you guys know any solution or work around for this case, please let me know. Any idea would be more than welcome.

Thank you in advance, guys!

Below is the code:

Map using FlatList

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow strict-local
 */

import React, {useCallback, useState} from 'react';
import {FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View,} from 'react-native';
import Stack from "./src/Stack";

const generateCell = (cellNumber: number): Array<string> => {

    let table = [];

    for (let j = 0; j < cellNumber; ++j) {
        table.push(String(j));
    }

    return table;
};

const App = () => {

    const [cellList] = useState(generateCell(6400));

    const [scrollable, setScrollable] = useState(true);

    const keyExtractorHorizontal = useCallback((item, index) => item.stackId + '-' + index.toString(), []);

    const keyExtractorVertical = useCallback((item, index) => item.stackId + '-' + index.toString(), []);

    // BUTTON

    const onPress = () => {
        setScrollable(!scrollable);
    }

    // RENDER

    const renderCell = ({index}: { index: number }) => {
        console.log('renderCell called', index);
        return (
            <Stack index={index}/>
        )
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.buttonContainer}
                onPress={onPress}
            >
                <Text>
                    Enable/Disable Scroll
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <FlatList
                scrollEnabled={scrollable}
                horizontal={true}
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                keyExtractor={keyExtractorHorizontal}
                data={[0]}
                extraData={cellList}
                windowSize={100}
                renderItem={() => {
                    return (
                        <FlatList
                            scrollEnabled={scrollable}
                            removeClippedSubviews={false}
                            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                            keyExtractor={keyExtractorVertical}
                            data={cellList}
                            extraData={cellList}
                            renderItem={renderCell}
                            windowSize={3}
                            numColumns={80}
                            initialNumToRender={10}
                        />
                    );
                }}
            />
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },

    buttonContainer: {
        width: '100%',
        height: 80,

        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    }
});

export default App;
```

Cell inside map, I call it "Stack"

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow strict-local
 */

import React from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';

const Stack = (props: {
    index: number
}) => {
    console.log('truly render stack', props.index);
    return (
        <View style={
            {
                height: 60,
                width: 60,
                borderColor: 'black',
                borderWidth: 1,
            }
        }/>
    );
};

export default React.memo(Stack);
```

Comment: i dont think it is good idea to render `FlatList` within a `FlatList`. perhaps you can use some grouping logic via the cell's index.

Comment: @kenmistry: thank you for your quick comment. We will have to scroll 2 directions, so I guess the we can not avoid 2 ScrollView/FlatList. I also try the 2 dimension grouping logic but it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to achieve the virtualized grid layout and since every grid size is same you can use [numColumns](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#numcolumns) in Flatlist (vertical) that will divide the list to that number of columns. Using Flatlist inside a Flatlist surely is not a problem for less data but the nested Flatlist child count has to be recomputed on each parent Flatlist, it might be the issue for slugginess.

Comment: thank you for the nested FlatList information. I am using the numColumns as you said. However, I think there is no way to avoid the nested FlatList, because I need to scroll both direction.